# Words like 'maybe', 'possibly', 'might' 'likely'

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, modality

**What is the technical term for words that indicate probability?**

For example:

> You *might* mean this, but *possibly* that instead.
>
> And some such words can be tagged on the end, *maybe*

I thought of 'filler' to start with, but that's more like, 'like', and um, 'um'.

I'm *pretty sure* there is one, but it's gone from me.

Comment: << **Modality** is the grammaticalized expression of the subjective attitudes and opinions of the speaker including possibility, probability, necessity, obligation, permissibility, ability, desire, and contingency. >>[[Linguistics Girl](http://www.linguisticsgirl.com/linguistic-definition-of-modality/)], but check her sources before dismissing this outright. See also the [study.com](http://study.com/academy/lesson/modal-adverbs-definition-interpretation-examples.html) article on _modal adverbs_.

Comment: Informally you could call them ***weasel words***

Comment: I think they are, for the most part, adverbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Edwin that if your question is the technical term for any word that talks about probability of an action, including "definitely" or "never", that **modal adverb** is the way to go.

However, I see that all of your examples say that something may or may not happen, and that the word that comes into your mind is *filler*. If you specifically mean words that serve no purpose other than to make a sentence weaker, then I think the word you want is **hedge** or **qualifier**.

According to the Oxford New American Dictionary, a **hedge** is "a word or phrase used to allow for additional possibilities or to avoid commitment, for example, etc., often, usually, or sometimes". *Might*, *possibly*, and *maybe* in your example are textbook hedges.

A **[qualifier](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/qualifiers/)**, technically, can weaken or intensify a statement ("very" is a qualifier), but it's common to say that someone is *qualifying* or *adding a qualifier* and simply to mean that they are hedging. For example, [this article](http://uproxx.com/news/trump-return-rant-lies-media-fake-news-enemy/) describes saying that something is "my opinion" as a qualifier.

Jim's example of **[weasel words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Words_to_watch#Unsupported_attributions)** may also fit your usage, but note that it includes many words that don't deal with probability, and carries a stronger connotation that the person using them is being dishonest.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was confused with modal verbs (I spoke to my English teacher about it!). The other options work as well...